# show alert while app is in background swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uialertcontroller

I have a sort of 'Alarm app' which should give the user a sound noise when a certain timer reaches zero.
Just for testing purposes I implemented notifications because I don't figure out how to show an alert controller while the app is in background.
Moreover, the notification works quite well but in the simulation it gives me the alarm sound that I chose, whereas in my iphone it uses the standard chime of my notification settings.
In conclusions I have two issues:
1. is it possible to show alert controller while the app is in background
2. while I have two different sounds when a notification occur. I implemented the notification as the following

In `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

in `applicationWillResignActive`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("scheduleNotifications", object: self)
```

where `scheduleNotifications` is implemented as a method of my ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to run arbitrary code while your app is in the background.

If the functionality of your app falls within one of Apple's defined exceptions (such as playing music or providing GPS navigation), then there are APIs available to continue to perform that task in the background.  That doesn't seem to apply in your case.

As far as sounds go, see Point 4 under 'Scheduling Local Notifications' [in this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).
The short answer is that you should be able to use the `soundName` property to provide a custom sound.

Comment: so it is not possible to show an AlertController while my app is in background. I'll have a look at that link. Thanks

Comment: amazing that worked: just writing localNotification.soundName = "sound.wav" thanks for the tip I didn't find that link!

Comment: sapi do you think that it is possible to repeat the sound until the user scroll the badge? It does not seem possible from the developer guide...

Comment: @Nicholas I don't think it will be possible to repeat the sound.  You're largely constrained by the local notifications API, and as far as I'm aware it doesn't support this.

Comment: the link to apple documentation is broken